# Will this power2max power meter be compatible with Cannondale Synapse?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, power

I have a 2015 Cannondale Synapse - specifically, this one: http://www.swiftcycles.co.uk/334/products/2015-cannondale-synapse-carbon-105-6-road-bike.aspx. I would like to add a power meter, and power2max looks like the best option to me because it looks very universal as I upgrade other stuff. Over the next few years, I'm sure I will replace my wheels, maybe my pedals (considering Speed Play) and almost certainly the bike itself. As power2max spiders off the chainset, the only thing this power meter would limit me to is crank and chainset - and I'm happy to stay with a compact at the moment.

The Synapse as far as I understand has a BB30A bottom bracket, which I believe means that the crank diameter has to be 30mm. 24mm cranks seem to be compatible with more frames, so I am looking to instead purchase the following:

- power2max Type S power meter with 110mm BCD
- Rotor 3D24 cranks with 172.5mm crank length (matching my current cranks).
- Keep my existing chain rings & pedals (Ultegra pedals)
- Rotor BB30to24 bottom bracket
- Unsure whether or not I need to purchase chain ring bolts - can I use my existing ones?

As far I'm aware, that *should* all work with my BB30A bottom bracket. Before I shell out a load of money, I just want to make sure this is all correct - look forward to hearing what you all have to say. Thanks!

Comment: I presume you asked Power2Max? What did they say?

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  That's a well formed and detailed question, thank you for asking clearly.

Comment: @R.Chung yes, though it has left me confused. In their original email they suggested the 3D24 crankset, but then said "with your current bottom bracket" - but my current BB is a BB30A which as far as I know *isn't* compatible with 3D24 - at least not without shims. They also said "if you have the new four bolt Shimano crank you need new chainrings", but I have 5 bolt chainrings so I assume they are OK.

Comment: Was this for a BB30 version of the Type S? The difference between the BB30 and the BB30A is that the "A" has 5mm of extra width on the left side BB shell. Check for clearance there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can install a Type S - Rotor 3D24 on your Synapse using the following adapter:

https://www.c-bear.com/en/products/bb30a-cannondale-synapse

You also have the option of Type S - FSA MegaExo (Gossamer or K-Force Light) and Type S - FSA BB386EVO (Gossamer or K-Force Light). Please have a look at the following chart from FSA:

http://www.fullspeedahead.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/POSTER-BB-2014-ROAD-A234.pdf

If you have any other question, please feel fre to ask !

Andrés
power2max Team

Comment: Awesome, thanks Andres! Look forward to placing my order in the next few days ;)

Comment: This chart came in handy https://www.c-bear.com/bbchart.pdf